# Laravel File Manager

Tags: php, laravel

Установил по гайду Laravel FileManager (с офф гитхаба), но при открытии /laravel-filemanager возвращается просто 1. ничего больше, только цифра 1. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Что значит ''c офф гитхаба"? Я нашёл на просторе три разных Laravel FileManager... Если хочешь чтобы помогли - пиши развёрнутый вопрос